# Why is there a black background of a file with a transparent png posted on top of a regular pdf?

Tags: python, image, cs50, paste

I'm pasting a transparent png that should only take up the bottom of the new image when it is pasted on top of a picture; however, when I paste it on top of the image, it shows the pasted png part, and then the rest above it is all black. I was wondering how I could fix it and if it has something to do with the masking of the pasted png?

```
import sys
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

def main():
    def paster(inp, output):
        shirt = Image.open('shirt.png')
        initial = Image.open(inp)
        #making size variable to use to resize shirt png before pasting it
        size = initial.size
        p = ImageOps.fit(shirt, size, method=Image.BICUBIC, bleed=0.0, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
        #pasting shirt 'p' over initial image
        initial.paste(p)
        initial.save(output)


    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        sys.exit('Too few command-line arguments')
    elif len(sys.argv) > 3:
        sys.exit('Too many command-line arguments')
    else:
       paster(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You are resizing the wrong image in `ImageOps.fit()` (and setting
   way too many unneeded parameters). Resize `initial` to be the same
   size as `shirt`, and use the default values (don't add keyword parameters).
2. Define the `mask=` parameter when you paste.